# How to dynamically validate input created by ngFor

Tags: angular, forms, validation

So I have following piece of code,

```
<div *ngFor="let test of testModel; index as i">
    <input [(ngModel)]="test.key" name="inputTest{{i}}" required="true"
                                id="inputTest{{i}}" #inputTest{{i}}="ngModel" />

<p *ngIf="inputTest{{i}}.errors?.required"> // Error Line
      Field is required!
</p>
</div>
```

How can I validate the input fields which have dynamic id, what is the correct way to write ngIf in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can look at https://angular.io/guide/forms it explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `formArray`, please find below a working example!

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  form: FormGroup;
  
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      person: this.fb.array([])
    });
    this.addRows()
  }

  addRows() {
    let ctrl = <FormArray>this.form.controls.person;
    ctrl.push(this.fb.group({
      'name': ['', Validators.required],
      'info': ['', Validators.required]
    }))
  }
}
```

html

```
<label class="label">Form array example with validation</label>

<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="person">
    <div
      *ngFor="let p of form.controls.person.controls; let i = index"
      [formGroupName]="i"
    >
      <label for="name">name:</label>
      <input
        [ngClass]="{ error: !p.controls.name.valid && p.controls.name.dirty }"
        formControlName="name"
        id="name"
        type="text"
      />
      <p *ngIf="p.controls.name.errors?.required">Field is required!</p>
      <label for="name">info:</label>
      <input
        [ngClass]="{ error: !p.controls.info.valid && p.controls.info.dirty }"
        formControlName="info"
        id="name"
        type="text"
      />
      <input style="margin-top: 10px" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid" />
      <input
        style="margin-top: 10px"
        type="button"
        value="add Row"
        (click)="addRows()"
      />
      <p *ngIf="p.controls.info.errors?.required">Field is required!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>
</form>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formarray-validation-blzzat)

Comment: @shreyshah does this change fix your issue?